# Customise flutter navbar / tabbar with individual background colors

Tags: flutter, navbar, background-color, tabbar

In both a tabbar and nav bar, I would like the selected tab to have a different background to the rest of the bar.

For example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKXyj.jpg

Is this possible in flutter?

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using stateful Widget, you could just set the state of the currentIndex in the on Tap method

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentIndex = 0;
  }


  BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                backgroundColor: currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.green : Colors.black,
                title: Text('0'),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                backgroundColor: currentIndex == 1 ? Colors.green : Colors.black,
                title: Text('1'),
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: currentIndex,
            onTap: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    currentIndex = index;
                });
                _navigateToPage(index);
            },
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChangeBottomNavBarTextColor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ChangeBottomNavBarTextColorState createState() {
    return new ChangeBottomNavBarTextColorState();
  }
}

class ChangeBottomNavBarTextColorState
    extends State<ChangeBottomNavBarTextColor> {
  String text = 'Home';


  var curIndex = 0;

  _onTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      curIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Change Bottom Nav Bar Text Color Example"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(text,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            )),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
        currentIndex: curIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
            ),
            title: Text("Home", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal)),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
            ),
            title: Text("Favorite", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink)),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
            ),
            title: Text("Profile", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.brown)),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(
              Icons.info,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.settings,
            ),
            title: Text("Settings", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber)),
          ),
        ],
        onTap: _onTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use something like that. When you clicked, `_onTap` function will change `currentIndex`. Then `selectedItemColor` will define the color of the selected index. You can play with the colors whatever you want.